# Monero gui deamon and mining

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

After syncing (took ages for the full but synqued in one go)  After that i want to start mining but the deamon disconnect and keeps disconnecting.  Also no writing to the log after 2 seconds mining.

BTW CPU mining Windows srv 2019 with 24 proc's using half (12)

Any idea's?

Nobody ??? the program is useless now.

Comment: Start by diagnosing the issues with the monerod (monero node) connectivity.